# Replace or remove of data in sqlite3 database using shell interpreter

Tags: python, shell, sqlite

how can i replace or null  value in sqlite3 database. In fact i am working in the **python shell interpreter** in **Ubuntu**. I have already been inserted value in my database namely

```
car.db
```

my table name is car_car and these are my fields,

```
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
"time_created" datetime NOT NULL,
"speed" integer NOT NULL
```

now i have already been inserted value against **name** , **time_created** and **speed**  field just like that in the **Shell ineterpreter**,

```
 val = Car('name'= 'test' , time_created = 'some_values' , speed = 'some_values')
```

What i am want to do  is that just replace those values with some new values or null those field individually .Now my question is that is there is any way to null or replace the field individually  using a single statement?

Please give me a solution, thank you

Comment: A plain variable such as `val` has nothing to do with SQLite. How did you actually insert your data?

Comment: after taking values in 'val' variable i just write the code in the shell interpreter,that is >> val.save().then it is inserted in the database.

Comment: And what library or framework implements that `save` method?